# ESLint: "'prop-types' should be listed in the project's dependencies", but "prop-types" is already included with "next" npm package (react/prop-types)

Tags: reactjs, next.js, eslint, react-proptypes

I'm using the `next` npm package which already requires the `prop-types` library. `prop-types` works as expected when I import it.

[image]

The problem is ESLint is telling me "'prop-types' should be listed in the project's dependencies". I've attempted to set the ESLint rule:

```
  "rules": {
    "react/prop-types": "off",
  },
```

also

```
"rules": {
    ...
    "import/no-extraneous-dependencies": [
      "error", {
        "devDependencies": true,
        "optionalDependencies": true,
        "peerDependencies": true,
        "bundledDependencies": true
      }
    ]
}
```

However, the ESLint error is still being detected. I don't want to add `prop-types` to my `package.json` because it's already included with `next`. I've seen that these attempts have worked for React.js apps, but it does seem to be working for my Next.js app. Is there anyone that could shed more light on this issue I'm having?

Comment: ah. okay. Thanks @brc-dd!

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't matter which package is having which dependency, if you're directly using a package, it is recommended that it should be your dependency too. I'm not one of the developers of `eslint-plugin-import`, but the inspiration behind the rule would probably have been somewhat like this:

- It may happen that a package `foo` may stop bundling a certain package `bar` with it, or maybe `foo` changes `bar`'s version. But since which packages a package internally use don't affect semantic versioning until the exposed methods and behavior are the same, you may not even get a major version update. This means that you'll still have `"foo": "^a.b.c"` in your `package.json`, but `bar` will be updated. And if you are using `bar` without explicitly specifying it in your dependencies, you're are left with a code that may not work as intended, or may not work at all.

Now coming to your problem, you need to disable [`import/no-extraneous-dependencies`](https://github.com/import-js/eslint-plugin-import/blob/master/docs/rules/no-extraneous-dependencies.md) to ignore that (linter) warning/error. To do that you can refer the docs: [Disabling Rules with Inline Comments](https://eslint.org/docs/2.13.1/user-guide/configuring#disabling-rules-with-inline-comments) and [Configuring Rules](https://eslint.org/docs/2.13.1/user-guide/configuring#configuring-rules). However, the simplest method will be to keep using the rule, and just ignoring it for a line:

```
// eslint-disable-next-line import/no-extraneous-dependencies
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
```